# Show a png Image with lodePng and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to load a png image with lodepng (http://lodev.org/lodepng/) and draw with openGl, but I'm getting an error and I think that I'm trying to access an inaccessible vector id. But I don't know why.

Main code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glut.h>
#include <vector>
#include "lodepng.h"

using namespace std;

std::vector<unsigned char> img;
unsigned w, h;

void decodeOneStep(const char* filename)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> image;
    unsigned width, height;

    //decode
    unsigned error = lodepng::decode(image, width, height, filename);
    cout << "w: " << width << " " << "h: " << height << endl;

    //if there's an error, display it
    if (error) std::cout << "decoder error " << error << ": " <<       lodepng_error_text(error) << std::endl;
    else
    {
        img = image;
        w = width;
        h = height;
        cout << "Success" << endl;
    }
}

void display(void)
{
    /*  clear all pixels  */
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glRasterPos2i(0,0);
    glDrawPixels(w,h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &img);


    glFlush ();
}

void init (void) 
{
    /*  select clearing (background) color       */
    glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

    decodeOneStep("eleTest.png");
    cout << img->size();
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize (800, 800); 
    glutInitWindowPosition (300, 0);
    glutCreateWindow ("hello");
    init ();
    glutDisplayFunc(display); 
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

and the error is:
[image]

Comment: Try to debug de code and run it line by line, do you know at what lime does it crash?

Comment: Yep, it's crash at the line I call glDrawPixels ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your data does not match the type qualifier in `glDrawPixels`

```
std::vector<unsigned char> img;
glDrawPixels(w,h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &img);
```

img contains 1 byte of data per channel, but tell OpenGL that it should read 4 bytes (one integer) per channel. Try to switch GL_UNSIGNED_INT to GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE.

Since I don't know the importer library: You will have to ensure that the image really has an alpha channel. Otherwise you might get a similar to problem.

Note that `&img` is not necessarily the address of the first element in the vector. You should at least use `&img[0]`, as also shown in the opengl example of LodePNG.

Comment: I got it, so, I'm sure this image has a alpha channel because is a png 512x512 and when I show the vector size the value is 1048576  = 512*512*4(channels). 
I tried to switch to unsigned byte (it's really makes more sense), but i got the same error.

Comment: Habe you also switched to `&img[0]`?